# What's the easiest way to tell a spring bean to treat specific values as null?

Tags: spring

I have a bean with a date field, configured as follows:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="mm/dd/yyyy")
private Date paymentReceived;
```

I create this bean by reading some data (textual) from a service, constructing a FieldSet object and use a BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper with the FieldSet object.

Sometimes, the text values are "N/A" and there I want to put a null as the property value. Another important thing - I have multiple fields that behave the same.

What would be the easiest way (similar to the DateTimeFormat that I used for parsing the string) to tell spring to "ignore" specific values?
I'd rather have the configuration as an annotation in the bean class and not in the XML file.

Many thanks!

Comment: Dave, How do I set a converter for a specific property? Couldn't find any relevant annotation..

Answer (score 1):

I think what Dave Newton is suggesting is to create your own [PropertyEditorSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyEditorSupport.html). List of the different PropertyEditors Spring provides can be found [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion).

You can then let Spring know to use that property editor whenever it needs to convert String to Dates by either:

1. [Registering that custom PropertyEditorSupport with your BeanFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableBeanFactory.html#registerCustomEditor%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class%29).
2. Creating your own CustomPropertyRegistrar and [CustomEditorConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/CustomEditorConfigurer.html) for your date PropertyEditorSupport.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to use PropertyEditorSupport to convert from String to Date, but can I register it for a specific property? (not all Dates)